# How not to count space as a char using foldLeft

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an exercise where I have to check how many DIFFERENT chars are used in a string.
I don't know how not to count space as a char. I wanted to put if inside the foldLeft, like:

```
str.foldLeft(lista)((acc, char) => if (char != ' ') char :: acc)
```

but then it says that required List[Char], found: Any.
What do you generally also think about my function? Could I do it faster/more effectivly?

```
def countChars(str: String): Int = {
    val lista = List[Char]()
    val letters = str.foldLeft(lista)((acc, char) => char :: acc)

    val result = letters.toSet.size


    return result
  }
  println(countChars("hello world"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is "faster or more efficiently", maybe a little bit, but certainly reads better and is more idiomatic :)

```
   str.iterator.filterNot(_.isWhitespace).distinct.size
```

Or alternatively

```
   str.iterator.distinct.count(!_.isWhitespace)
```

If you are set on using `foldLeft` then folding into `Set` would save you a few ticks compared to creating a list first, and then converting it into set:

```
   str.foldLeft(Set.empty[Char]) { 
      case (s, ' ') => s
      case (s, c) => s + c
   }.size
```

Or you could get rid of the space afterwards:

```
   (str.foldLeft(Set.empty[Char])(_ + _) - ' ').size
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use `Set` as accumulator from the start. Then you can use if-else and return current accumulator if current char should not be counted:

```
val set = Set[Char]()
val uniqueCount = str.foldLeft(set)((acc, char) => if (char != ' ')  acc + char else acc)
    .size
```

Comment: thank you. I was close, but I just didn't know what to write in else :)
I have one question: I don't know when to use :+, ::, +. I saw you using "+". What's the difference and when can I use those options which I mentioned?

Comment: @squall it depends on collection which you are using and what you want to do =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching. Then you don't need the `if...else`.

```
def countChars(str: String): Int =
  str.foldLeft(Set[Char]()){
    case (acc, ' ') => acc
    case (acc, c)   => acc + c
  }.size
```